# Purpose of an explicitly scoped block in Go?

Tags: go, lexical-scope

I'm reading this source code in the MicroMDM SCEP repository, https://github.com/micromdm/scep/blob/1e0c4b782f3f2e1e6f81da5f82444a6cedc89df3/cmd/scepclient/scepclient.go#L54-L65:

```
func run(cfg runCfg) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var logger log.Logger
    {
        if strings.ToLower(cfg.logfmt) == "json" {
            logger = log.NewJSONLogger(os.Stderr)
        } else {
            logger = log.NewLogfmtLogger(os.Stderr)
        }
        stdlog.SetOutput(log.NewStdlibAdapter(logger))
        logger = log.With(logger, "ts", log.DefaultTimestampUTC)
        if !cfg.debug {
            logger = level.NewFilter(logger, level.AllowInfo())
        }
    }
    lginfo := level.Info(logger)
```

I wonder what the purpose is of the explicit block (the outer `{ ... }`)? Would this code not be exactly the same as if they were removed, like

```
func run(cfg runCfg) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var logger log.Logger
    if strings.ToLower(cfg.logfmt) == "json" {
        logger = log.NewJSONLogger(os.Stderr)
    } else {
        logger = log.NewLogfmtLogger(os.Stderr)
    }
    stdlog.SetOutput(log.NewStdlibAdapter(logger))
    logger = log.With(logger, "ts", log.DefaultTimestampUTC)
    if !cfg.debug {
        logger = level.NewFilter(logger, level.AllowInfo())
    }
    lginfo := level.Info(logger)
```

Perhaps the explicit block is just to improve legibility?

Comment: There is no purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case there seems to be no purpose to the extra block. No variables are declared inside the block. It doesn't add clarity, instead it's confusing you.

If clarity were desired you'd extract that code into a new function to initialize the logger.

```
func initLogger(cfg runCfg) log.Logger {
    var logger log.Logger

    if strings.ToLower(cfg.logfmt) == "json" {
        logger = log.NewJSONLogger(os.Stderr)
    } else {
        logger = log.NewLogfmtLogger(os.Stderr)
    }
    stdlog.SetOutput(log.NewStdlibAdapter(logger))
    logger = log.With(logger, "ts", log.DefaultTimestampUTC)
    if !cfg.debug {
        logger = level.NewFilter(logger, level.AllowInfo())
    }

    return logger
}

func run(cfg runCfg) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    logger := initLogger(cfg)
    lginfo := level.Info(logger)
    ...
```

My best guess is this block served some purpose in the past and whoever changed the code did not remove it, possibly also not sure if still served a purpose. Looking through the blame log of this function might give you an answer.

Comment: You are calling `initLogger` with the wrong parameter. It needs a config, not a context type.

Comment: @colminator Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a moment to read the rest of the code, these blocks are [all over the code](https://github.com/micromdm/scep/blob/master/cmd/scepserver/scepserver.go#L125-L149). In these cases though, there **are** short-lived variables that are declared and this is a method for discarding them after they are no longer needed. The two most likely scenarios are that there might have been some for the logger, or that it's just the particular style the developer has chosen. Actually, both are likely true.

It's a bit of an odd style for Go, but is effective at explicitly telling the garbage collector, as well as the developer, that these have gone out of scope. However, the Go compiler and GC are advanced enough as of writing to know when these can be discarded anyway, so there is little benefit to the program itself other than de-cluttering the current scope's namespace.

I am in agreement with @Schwern though, it adds clarity and accomplishes the same results to refactor these into their own functions. If someone is taking the time to explicitly declare scoping blocks, then why not use that time to make them functions instead?

Linked code block:

```
var svc scepserver.Service // scep service
{
    svcOptions := []scepserver.ServiceOption{
        scepserver.ChallengePassword(*flChallengePassword),
        scepserver.WithCSRVerifier(csrVerifier),
        scepserver.CAKeyPassword([]byte(*flCAPass)),
        scepserver.ClientValidity(clientValidity),
        scepserver.AllowRenewal(allowRenewal),
        scepserver.WithLogger(logger),
    }
    svc, err = scepserver.NewService(depot, svcOptions...)
    if err != nil {
        lginfo.Log("err", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    svc = scepserver.NewLoggingService(log.With(lginfo, "component", "scep_service"), svc)
}

var h http.Handler // http handler
{
    e := scepserver.MakeServerEndpoints(svc)
    e.GetEndpoint = scepserver.EndpointLoggingMiddleware(lginfo)(e.GetEndpoint)
    e.PostEndpoint = scepserver.EndpointLoggingMiddleware(lginfo)(e.PostEndpoint)
    h = scepserver.MakeHTTPHandler(e, svc, log.With(lginfo, "component", "http"))
}
```

Comment: If a block of code is only used once (or called from only one location) moving that to a (global) function moves the logic away from where it really belongs. It's a style for sure, but from a readability perspective, nested code does shows at a glance it's place in the code hierarchy.

Comment: And even if a function is needed (i.e. needs to be called from 2 or more places) but only from within a single function/method scope, defining the function inline conveys meaningful design.

Comment: @colminator Note, the function is private to the package. Functions are for so much more than calling the same code twice. The logic has not moved away, the call is still there, only the details have been encapsulated. The reader now has the option to skim at a high level: grab the background context, initialize the logger, set the log level to info. If the reader wants more detail about a particular part they can *optionally* go read the function docs and code. Finally, giving the logic its own function allows it to be named, documented, unit tested, refactored in isolation, and *reused*.

Comment: There's no wrong answer. Its just a style. But even if the function is a lowercase non-public function, it can in theory be called from anywhere - which is what I meant by "global" i.e global scope sense. As for unittesting, that should be done at the outer level - especially if the inner function is relatively simple.

Comment: My take on using functions was exactly as @Schwern noted. I do agree it's partially an issue of style, but smaller, discrete blocks of code as functions make things more clear and is easier to unit test. The code linked here could simply be two functions, then when reading the calling function, it's easier to see these two operations without all the unnecessary meta/config info to clutter up the function.

Comment: @colminator That it's possible to hack into private methods do not make them global anymore than breaking down a locked door means it was open. Calling private methods is a technique of *last resort*. If you find yourself *regularly* grabbing at private methods you either have poorly designed packages, or you're a kleptomaniac. :) As for unit testing, unit testing is done at the *unit* level so you're only testing one thing at a time before they're integrated. Initializing these objects is a clear unit.